# IBM Mobile First - mfpdev-cli Installation Failure

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, ibm-mobilefirst

I have issue while installing npm mfpdev-cli (IBM Mobile First CLI).

I am using node v `6.11.2` npm v `5.4.1`

I am unable to install mfpdev-cli. I am getting the below error:

**Error message:**

```
npm ERR! path /Users/divya/Desktop/MFP/mdo-windows-support/package.json

npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON

npm ERR! errno -2

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! package.json ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/divya/Desktop/MFP/mdo-windows-support/package.json'

npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
```

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /Users/divya/.npm/_logs/2017-09-12T03_05_20_995Z-debug.log

**Message:**

I ran the installation in the current working directory which has Package.json file but the error says the package.json doesn't exist. The path, it is showing is not right- "/Users/divya/Desktop/MFP/mdo-windows-support/package.json". It has to be "Users/divya/Desktop/MFP/nzrb-tab-mobilefirst/package.json". How do I change the path?

I am not sure what causing this issue. Much appreciated your help/suggestions.

Comment: The Error clearly says that your `Package.Json` is not there. Check whether you have that file..

Comment: Package.json was there. The problem was with my npm version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IBM MobileFirst CLI is not supported in the npm version whatever you are trying with.

Try installing the same with npm version `3.10.10` and this should resolve the issue which you are facing.

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you so much. You made my day :)

Comment: i am getting this same issue... Does that mean you need to downgrade ur npm ?